# Activating LVM volumes after failure to attach after reboot

Tags: usb, 22.04, lvm, proxmox

I currently have the problem that after every reboot the two external hard disks (both connected via USB) throw the error "Activating LVM volumes after failure to attach ...".
Normally I can then reactivate them as described [here](https://talhamangarah.com/blog/proxmox-7-activating-lvm-volumes-after-failure-to-attach-on-boot/)

Here briefly as an example for sdbthin

```
lvchange -an sdbthin/sdbthin_tmeta
lvchange -an sdbthin/sdbthin_tdata
vgchange -ay
```

Is there a way to avoid this? for example

- clean shutdown before reboot
- clean mount after reboot

Not sure where to start!

Many thanks